# Who said many agados were to wake students?

Tags: torah-study, midrash, sleep, agada-stories-legends, talmud-bavli

Someone told me this morning that he had, years before, seen a commentary published in the back of a volume of *g'mara*, likely *Maharsha* or *Maharam*, say that many of the *agados* throughout *shas* were said in order to break up the dry material and keep students awake. He has been unable to find this and asked me if I knew where it is. I did (and do) not, and turn to you.

Comment: This was also done during actual lectures (*Shir HaShirim Rabba*, 1:15:3): רבי היה יושב ודורש ונתנמנם הציבור, בקש לעוררן אמר ילדה אשה אחת במצרים ששים רבוא בכרס אחת, והיה שם תלמיד אחד ורבי ישמעאל ברבי יוסי שמו אמר ליה מאן הות כן, אמר ליה זו יוכבד שילדה את משה ששקול כנגד ששים רבוא של ישראל.

Comment: @Fred, yes, also the one about _Sara_'s 127 years and _Ester_'s 127 states (though I don't know where that is).

Comment: *B'reishis Rabba* (58:3): רבי עקיבא היה יושב ודורש והצבור מתנמנם בקש לעוררן אמר מה ראתה אסתר שתמלוך על שבע ועשרים ומאה מדינה אלא תבא אסתר שהיתה בת בתה של שרה שחיתה ק' וכ' וז' ותמלוך על ק' וכ' וז' מדינות.

Comment: Gemara Pesachim is shayach. I also don't recall specifically where it is.

Answer (score 6):

The Rashb"o in Chindushai HaHagodos (Mosad Horav Kook) to Brochos 54b states that after a long halachik discussion the Ameroim switched to Agadato to awaken the students.